# How to end trial after timeout in jsPsych

Tags: jspsych

I would like to ask for advice regarding a custom jsPsych plugin for a serial reaction time task, that was created by [@vekteo](https://github.com/vekteo), and is available [in Gorilla](https://app.gorilla.sc/openmaterials/397611), where the code can be edited and tested.

By default, trials are self-paced, but I would need them to time out after 2,000 ms. I am struggling to achieve this, and would be very grateful if someone could please advise me a bit. Several attempts have proven unsuccessful (please see [this discussion](https://github.com/jspsych/jsPsych/discussions/3223)).

First, I tried setting trial duration using the parameters provisioned in the original code, specifically in the `groupStart.trial_duration` property in the `main` script. Unfortunately, this does not work. Next, I have focussed on the the script `jspsych-serial-reaction-time`, which contains the core plugin for the task. Please find this script below.

In this plugin, trials are finished using the custom function `endTrial`, which gathers important data before calling `jsPsych.finishTrial(trial_data)`. In the plugin below, `endTrial` is used successfully to finish trials after a response. However, I wonder how this function could be repurposed to end trials after 2,000 ms.

```
/**
 * jspsych-serial-reaction-time
 * Josh de Leeuw
 *
 * plugin for running a serial reaction time task
 *
 * documentation: docs.jspsych.org
 *
 **/

jsPsych.plugins["serial-reaction-time"] = (function() {

  var plugin = {};

  plugin.info = {
    name: 'serial-reaction-time',
    description: '',
    parameters: {
      grid: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.BOOL,
        pretty_name: 'Grid',
        array: true,
        default: [[1,1,1,1]],
        description: 'This array represents the grid of boxes shown on the screen.'
      },
      target: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.INT,
        pretty_name: 'Target',
        array: true,
        default: undefined,
        description: 'The location of the target. The array should be the [row, column] of the target.'
      },
      choices: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.KEYCODE,
        pretty_name: 'Choices',
        array: true,
        default: [['3','5','7','9']],
        description: ' Each entry in this array is the key that should be pressed for that corresponding location in the grid.'
      },
      grid_square_size: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.INT,
        pretty_name: 'Grid square size',
        default: 100,
        description: 'The width and height in pixels of each square in the grid.'
      },
      target_color: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.STRING,
        pretty_name: 'Target color',
        default: "url(static/images/cat.jpg)",
        description: 'The color of the target square.'
      },
      response_ends_trial: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.BOOL,
        pretty_name: 'Response ends trial',
        default: true,
        description: 'If true, trial ends when user makes a response.'
      },
      pre_target_duration: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.INT,
        pretty_name: 'Pre-target duration',
        default: 0,
        description: 'The number of milliseconds to display the grid before the target changes color.'
      },
      trial_duration: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.INT,
        pretty_name: 'Trial duration',
        default: null,
        description: 'How long to show the trial.'
      },
      show_response_feedback: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.BOOL,
        pretty_name: 'Show response feedback',
        default: false,
        description: 'If true, show feedback indicating where the user responded and whether it was correct.'
      },
      feedback_duration: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.INT,
        pretty_name: 'Feedback duration',
        default: 200,
        description: 'The length of time in milliseconds to show the feedback.'
      },
      fade_duration: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.INT,
        pretty_name: 'Fade duration',
        default: null,
        description: 'If a positive number, the target will progressively change color at the start of the trial, with the transition lasting this many milliseconds.'
      },
      prompt: {
        type: jsPsych.plugins.parameterType.STRING,
        pretty_name: 'Prompt',
        default: null,
        no_function: false,
        description: ' Any content here will be displayed below the stimulus.'
      },
    }
  }

  plugin.trial = function(display_element, trial) {

    // create a flattened version of the choices array
    var flat_choices = jsPsych.utils.flatten(trial.choices);
    while(flat_choices.indexOf('') > -1){
      flat_choices.splice(flat_choices.indexOf(''),1);
    }

    // display stimulus
    var stimulus = this.stimulus(trial.grid, trial.grid_square_size);
    display_element.innerHTML = stimulus;

        if(trial.pre_target_duration <= 0){
            showTarget();
        } else {
            jsPsych.pluginAPI.setTimeout(function(){
                showTarget();
            }, trial.pre_target_duration);
        }

        //show prompt if there is one
    if (trial.prompt !== null) {
      display_element.innerHTML += trial.prompt;
    }

        var keyboardListener = {};

    var response = {
      rt: null,
      key: false,
      correct: false
    }

        function showTarget(){
      if(trial.fade_duration == null){
        display_element.querySelector('#jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-cell-'+trial.target[0]+'-'+trial.target[1]).style.background = trial.target_color;
        display_element.querySelector('#jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-cell-'+trial.target[0]+'-'+trial.target[1]).style.backgroundSize = "contain";
      } else {
        display_element.querySelector('#jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-cell-'+trial.target[0]+'-'+trial.target[1]).style.transition = "background-image "+trial.fade_duration;
        display_element.querySelector('#jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-cell-'+trial.target[0]+'-'+trial.target[1]).style.background = trial.target_color;
        display_element.querySelector('#jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-cell-'+trial.target[0]+'-'+trial.target[1]).style.backgroundSize = "contain";
      }

            keyboardListener = jsPsych.pluginAPI.getKeyboardResponse({
        callback_function: after_response,
        valid_responses: flat_choices,
        allow_held_key: false
      });

            if(trial.trial_duration > null){
                jsPsych.pluginAPI.setTimeout(showFeedback, trial.trial_duration);
            }

        }

    function showFeedback() {
      if(response.rt == null || trial.show_response_feedback == false){
        endTrial();
      } else {
        var color = response.correct ? '#0f0' : '#f00';
        display_element.querySelector('#jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-cell-'+response.responseLoc[0]+'-'+response.responseLoc[1]).style.transition = "";
        display_element.querySelector('#jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-cell-'+response.responseLoc[0]+'-'+response.responseLoc[1]).style.backgroundColor = color;
        jsPsych.pluginAPI.setTimeout(endTrial, trial.feedback_duration);
      }
    }

    function endTrial() {

      // kill any remaining setTimeout handlers
      jsPsych.pluginAPI.clearAllTimeouts();

      // kill keyboard listeners
      if (typeof keyboardListener !== 'undefined') {
        jsPsych.pluginAPI.cancelKeyboardResponse(keyboardListener);
      }

      // gather the data to store for the trial
      var trial_data = {
        "rt": response.rt,
        "key_press": response.key,
                "correct": response.correct,
                "grid": JSON.stringify(trial.grid),
                "target": JSON.stringify(trial.target)
      };

      // clear the display
      display_element.innerHTML = '';

      // move on to the next trial
      jsPsych.finishTrial(trial_data);

    };

    // function to handle responses by the subject
    function after_response(info) {

            // only record first response
      response = response.rt == null ? info : response;

            // check if the response is correct
            var responseLoc = [];
            for(var i=0; i<trial.choices.length; i++){
                for(var j=0; j<trial.choices[i].length; j++){
                    var t = typeof trial.choices[i][j] == 'string' ? jsPsych.pluginAPI.convertKeyCharacterToKeyCode(trial.choices[i][j]) : trial.choices[i][j];
                    if(info.key == t){
                        responseLoc = [i,j];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
      response.responseLoc = responseLoc;
            response.correct = (JSON.stringify(responseLoc) == JSON.stringify(trial.target));

            if (trial.response_ends_trial) {
        if (trial.show_response_feedback){
                showFeedback(response.correct);
            } else {
          endTrial();
        }
      }
    };

  };

  plugin.stimulus = function(grid, square_size, target, target_color, labels) {
    var stimulus = "<div id='jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus' style='margin:auto; display: table; table-layout: fixed; border-spacing:"+square_size/4+"px'>";
    for(var i=0; i<grid.length; i++){
      stimulus += "<div class='jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-row' style='display:table-row;'>";
      for(var j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++){
        stimulus += "<div class='jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-cell' id='jspsych-serial-reaction-time-stimulus-cell-"+i+"-"+j+"' "+
         "style='width:"+square_size+"px; height:"+square_size+"px; border-radius: 100px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align: center; font-size:"+square_size/2+"px;";
        if(grid[i][j] == 1){
          stimulus += "border: 2px solid black;"
        }
        if(typeof target !== 'undefined' && target[0] == i && target[1] == j){
          stimulus += "background-image: "+target_color+";"
        }
        stimulus += "'>";
        if(typeof labels !=='undefined' && labels[i][j] !== false){
          stimulus += labels[i][j]
        }
        stimulus += "</div>";
      }
      stimulus += "</div>";
    }
    stimulus += "</div>";

    return stimulus
  }

  return plugin;
})();
```

Thank you very much

---

I've also asked this question at https://github.com/jspsych/jsPsych/discussions/3223. As soon as solution arises, I will provide the link to the solution on the other site.